# File not Uploading in File Reader

Tags: javascript, php, filereader

I am using File Reader for selecting and uploading images.
My images are selected previewing but not uploaded when i hit submit button.

In upload.php the output of $_FILES is an empty array.

Where is problem?

html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <input id="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" type="file"/> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="upload">

    <div id="image-holder">

    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fileUpload").on('change', function() {
          //Get count of selected files
          var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
          var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
          var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
          var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
          image_holder.empty();
          if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
              //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
              for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) 
              {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                  $("<img />", {
                    "src": e.target.result,
                    "class": "thumb-image"
                  }).appendTo(image_holder);
                }
                image_holder.show();
                reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
              }
            } else {
              alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
          } else {
            alert("Pls select only images");
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

require_once './include/db_connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
print_r($_FILES);
die();

if(!empty($_FILES)){

    $targetDir = "upload/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile))

   {
        //insert file information into db table
 $sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
 echo 'file inserted';  
 }
    else
    {
        echo 'Query not working';
    }

}
else
{
    echo 'No file selected';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file input doesn't have a `name`.

The `name` of a form control is used to determine what key it will have in the submitted data. Controls without them will not be successful (i.e. will not appear in the submitted data at all).

Comment: Superb !
God bless you !

Comment: ok one more thing .... What if i want to restrict the size of the image in script?